# SQL COUNT Function to find number of a particular ddata

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a table called `FRUITS` and data in the table are as follows

```
APPLE
BANANA
APPLE
BANANA+APPLE
```

How to count the number of `APPLES` in the table `FRUITS`?

Comment: Technically, the answer is zero - there are no strings equal to or including `APPLES` in the sample data you provided. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited data like that. Read up on normalization.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp <nitpick>Technically, the OP asked for *the number of APPLES*, not *the count of occurrences of APPLES*, so the answer should still be 3 </nitpick> :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM FRUITS WHERE name like '%APPLE%'
```

Comment: This query gives result as 2,but the result should be 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruits WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, 'APPLE');
```

Comment: Why REGEXP_LIKE, if you are not using any regular expressions?

Comment: @Ramblin, `'APPLE'` *is* a regular expression. It means "match this string, anywhere".

Comment: @JeffreyKeymp True, but using a regex in this case is overkill, since a simple LIKE search is sufficient (I guess that's what Ramblin'Man suggested)

Comment: yes I agree that's what he would have *meant* - but I'm a stickler for accuracy (in other people's comments, at least) :)

Answer (score 0):

If some columns can contain APPLE more than one time, please put it in your question. If not, you can use the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fruits WHERE Your_Column='APPLE'
```

If Apple can show up with some other text, you can use this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fruits WHERE LEN(Your_Column)!=LEN(REPLACE(Your_Column,'APPLE',''))
```

I wrote for MSSQL, I don't know which sql server you are using.

Comment: can't we do with using decode and substr functions??...if yes plz help me with it...

Comment: That would be pointless as you didn't ask for a string, only the count. If you have wanted some string except 'apple', you could use that.

Comment: If this answer helped you and solved your problem, please click on the tick button next to this answer, below the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

select count(case [your_column] when 'APPLE' then 1 else null end) from fruits;